# Adding alpha mask to SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'm attempting to add an alpha mask to my SVG file but am having some problems. I couldn't find a way to do it with Illustrator, so instead I used Photoshop to add the alpha layer and resaved it as SVG. Looking at the SVG file itself, I don't see anything that would indicate there's an alpha layer, and I haven't been able to get it to work.

The effect I want is for you to only see the grey layer through the magnifying glass lens, instead it looks like this.

[image]

This is my Codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/xxdaWOa

And here is the actual raw text of the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="836" height="1032" viewBox="0 0 836 1032">
  <image x="153" y="216" width="530" height="599" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

SVGs don't have a background by default. So you shouldn't need to do anything to make the background areas transparent.

Given that, your statement "I'm attempting to add an alpha mask to my SVG file" doesn't really make much sense.  It does not need a mask.

The example SVG you link to consists solely of a bitmap PNG image.  But that image has a transparent background so it should work also. By that I mean that whatever you place the SVG in front of, should show through.

Note however that an SVG that consists solely of a bitmap image is pretty much pointless.  You would be better just to use that bitmap directly.  You are not getting any benefit from putting it inside an SVG file.

**Update**

Okay, so if you want to create an effect where an image is visible through the lens of your magnifying glass, then your mask image needs to be a circle that matches just the lens size and position, not the whole magnifying glass.  In a mask image, white areas represent the part of the image you want to keep, and black areas are the parts you want to be transparent.

Like so.

[image]

This is the image that you ought to have had in your SVG.

However as I said, you're wasting the benefits of using an SVG if you just put a single large bitmap in it.  You could use a small SVG like the following instead.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="530" height="599">
  <!-- areas masked with black become transparent -->
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
  <!-- areas masked with white remain visible -->
  <circle cx="170" cy="170" r="165" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Your main magnifying glass isn't suitable as a mask, but it can be used as an image to be superimposed over the masked background.  But again, that image could be a proper SVG (using vector shapes instead of a bitmap) and it would be a *lot* smaller.

But if you are going to use SVGs it would be simpler to use an SVG for the whole thing.  Especially if you are planning to move the lens about.
The `mask-image` property has some restrictions, and can be tricky to use.

Here's an example of doing it entirely within an SVG.

```css
svg {
  width: 530px;
  height: 599px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 530 599">
  <defs>
    <!-- Our circular lens mask -->
    <mask id="lens-mask">
      <!-- areas masked with black become transparent -->
      <rect width="530" height="599" fill="black"/>
      <!-- areas masked with white remain visible -->
      <circle cx="170" cy="170" r="165" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!-- Background image that we want to show through the lens -->
  <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/530/599" width="530" height="599"
         mask="url(#lens-mask)"/>
  <!-- Magnifying glass image that we will lay directly over the top -->
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvbYR.png" id="mag-glass"/>
</svg>
```

**Update 2**

I didn't add any movement to my last example, because you hadn't mentioned it in your question. I didn't want to complicate the example by adding unnecessary extras.

Here's an updated version which includes movement.  Hopefully this helps.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("my-svg");
var magGlass = document.getElementById("mag-glass");
var lensCircle = document.querySelector("#my-svg #lens-mask circle");

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);

function moveLens(evt) {
  var mouseTransform = "translate(" + (evt.offsetX - 170) + "," + (evt.offsetY - 170) + ")";
  lensCircle.setAttribute("transform", mouseTransform);
  magGlass.setAttribute("transform", mouseTransform);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 530px;
  height: 599px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 530 599" id="my-svg">
  <defs>
    <!-- Our circular lens mask -->
    <mask id="lens-mask">
      <!-- areas masked with black become transparent -->
      <rect width="530" height="599" fill="black"/>
      <!-- areas masked with white remain visible -->
      <circle cx="170" cy="170" r="165" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!-- Background image that we want to show through the lens -->
  <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/530/599" width="530" height="599"
         mask="url(#lens-mask)"/>
  <!-- Magnifying glass image that we will lay directly over the top -->
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvbYR.png" id="mag-glass"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: So in my actual code since this is a minimal example, I have several elements and am trying to create an effect where the magnifying glass moves around the screen, and only within the lens you're able to see "through" the rest of the layer. I thought the way to do that is to create an alpha mask, but I'm not sure how or why I have a png image instead of an SVG? I included the code to the SVG file, how is there a png file in it?

This is the effect I'm going for, any advice on what I should do? I used that as a template for trying to create my own version but can't figure it out.

Comment: Except in that example they use a png as the mask, I'm trying to use another layer instead. So you can only see the layer underneath where the lens is.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie If you look at your SVG, the only thing in it is an `<image>` element.   The (PNG) image itself is encoded as a data url (`data:xxx`).  Incidentally there is an error in your data url. It should be `image/png`, not `img/png`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean now about it being a png, I don't know how that happened. I've been trying to follow the "minimally reproducible example" in framing my question, and I think that has kept me from being able to convey what I'm trying to do. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but in the example you gave if I move the magnifying glass, it doesn't show the relative position of the image underneath, instead I always see the cat's face regardless of where on the screen it is.

Comment: I created this Codepen to illustrate what I'm trying to do. There's a black "lens" element and a blue "alpha" div containing some text. I need to show the blue div only where the black "lens" div is while that animation is playing.

I understand if I've taken too much of your time already, but I hope this at least clarifies what I was trying to do. I was worried if I included that code originally I would be told to post a shorter code example, but I don't know how to explain it without the context of the project I'm using it in.

Comment: Re your last codepen sample.  What did you want to be able to see through the lens of the magnifying glass?

Comment: I would want to only see the text through the magnifying glass. My use case is I'm going to be animating a bunch of letters and words and images in my "alpha" div. When the magnifying glass is animated, the lens will have a portal/xray effect where it's looking through the other divs.

So the lens is able to see only the alpha layer, but outside of the lens is unaffected. Am I explaining that clearly?

Comment: So instead of a static image that fits within the lens, I'm trying to see what's under the lens, but only on the alpha layer.